# How to leave only the columns satisfying the following condition?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, filtering, table

Consider the following pre-generated table:

```
tab = Join[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}], Table[{1}, 3], 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}], Table[{0}, 3], 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}], Table[{0}, 3], 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}], Table[{-1}, 3], 2]
```

It consists of the groups of 3 columns. In each group, the third column has values 0, 1, -1. How to leave only the groups for which the third column takes the specific value? I.e., if I choose -1, then, schematically, the selected table would look like

```
tabsel=RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}], Table[{-1}, 3], 2]
```

This is my solution:

```
ProductsSelected[i_,val_] := 
 If[tab[[1]][[3*(i - 1) + 3]] == val,
   tab[[All, Range[3*(i - 1) + 1, 3*i]]], {}]
Join[ProductsSelected[1,1],ProductsSelected[2,1],
ProductsSelected[3,1], ProductsSelected[4,1],2]
```

However, the part with `Join` is manual: I need to change it depending on the number of groups of columns.

Comment: Try `Join@@Map[Cases[Partition[#,3],{_,_,-1}]&,tab]` on your real data and see if it works.

Comment: `Join@@Map[Cases[Partition[#,3],{_,_,-1}]&,tab]` works correctly (at least on one test set and I see no reason for possible failure in general). My solution assumes that each row of *tab* is a multiple of 3 long. Bill's treats each row separately. This is a "salt to taste" situation. With my assumption, `Join @@ Cases[Partition[Flatten[tab], 3], {_, _, -1}]` also works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admit that I changed your data so that the $-1$s would not be in predictable positions or quantities and I increased the number of rows to have a better chance of having at least some $-1$s.

```mma
n = 6
tab = ArrayFlatten[{{
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}], RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {n, 1}], 
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}], RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {n, 1}], 
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}], RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {n, 1}], 
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}], RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {n, 1}]}}, 2]; 
MatrixForm[tab]
MatrixForm[Select[Partition[Flatten[tab], 3], #1[[3]] == -1 & ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1];
(tab = Join[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}], Table[{1}, 3], 
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}], Table[{0}, 3], 
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}], Table[{0}, 3], 
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}], Table[{-1}, 3], 2]) // TableForm

tab // Grid
```

$$\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 0.817389 & 0.11142 & 1 & 0.542247 & 0.231155 & 0 & 0.422851 & 0.247495 & 0 & 0.29287 & 0.208051 & -1 \\
 0.789526 & 0.187803 & 1 & 0.396006 & 0.700474 & 0 & 0.977172 & 0.825163 & 0 & 0.580474 & 0.128821 & -1 \\
 0.241361 & 0.0657388 & 1 & 0.211826 & 0.748657 & 0 & 0.925275 & 0.578056 & 0 & 0.306427 & 0.712012 & -1 \\
\end{array}$$

To remove the 3 columnns with `-1` as their last element:

```
(res = Partition[#, 3] & /@ tab // DeleteCases[#, {_, _, -1}, {2}] & //
     Map[Flatten]) // Grid
```

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 0.817389 & 0.11142 & 1 & 0.542247 & 0.231155 & 0 & 0.422851 & 0.247495 & 0 \\
 0.789526 & 0.187803 & 1 & 0.396006 & 0.700474 & 0 & 0.977172 & 0.825163 & 0 \\
 0.241361 & 0.0657388 & 1 & 0.211826 & 0.748657 & 0 & 0.925275 & 0.578056 & 0 \\
\end{array}$$